# Conditional Expectation And the Partition Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I was looking at a document that had the following assertion: "We have the following continuous analog of the partition theorem."

$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]f_X(X)$.

I was under the assumption that $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(y)dy$.

Could this perhaps be a typo and instead they meant

$\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]f_X(X)$?

If what the document said was indeed correct, could someone please explain why that equation is true?

Comment: Is the integral meant to have a dx term in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation should be:

$\qquad\mathsf E(Y)=\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R \mathsf E(Y\mid X{\,=\,}x)\,f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x$

It is *also* true that

$\qquad\mathsf E(Y)=\displaystyle\int_\Bbb R y\,f_Y(y)\,\mathrm d y$

---

For continuous real-valued random variables where the marginal and joint probability density functions do exist:

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) &= \int_\Bbb R y\,f_Y(y)\,\mathrm d y&&\text{by definition of expectation}\\[1ex]&= \int_\Bbb R y\int_\Bbb R f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)~f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y&&\text{Law of Total Probability}\\[1ex]&=\int_\Bbb R f_X(x)\int_\Bbb R y~f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x&&\text{Fubini's Theorem }\\[1ex]&=\int_\Bbb R f_X(x)\,\mathsf E(Y\mid X{\,=\,}x)\,\mathrm d x&&\text{by definition of conditional expectation}\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))&&\text{by definition of expectation} \end{align}$